# access json POST data sent from PHP cURL

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying to access POST data sent from this cURL request.

```
 $param = array(
        'foo' => 'bar',
        'bar' => 'foo'
    )
    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
        CURLOPT_URL => 'http://localhost/mysite/data.php',
        CURLOPT_POST => 'TRUE',
        CURLOPT_HEADER => TRUE,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE,
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
            'Content-Type: application/json',
            'Content-Length: '.strlen(json_encode($param))
        ),
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => json_encode($param),
        )
    );

$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
print_r($result);
```

In data.php I want to access the JSON sent from cURL and return data after some validations based on them. Please help me access json post data from `data.php`. So far, `data.php` only returns an empty post array.

```
print_r($_POST);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this `php://input`

example

```
echo json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
```

Comment: Thanks for your help and quick response!